# Is sed buggy when pattern is newline for a delete command?

Tags: linux, regex, sed, newlines

My goal is to print the content of a file up to (and excluding) a specific pattern and I'm using the following which works as expected (even when pattern is `^$`):

```
sed -n '/pattern/!p;//q' file
```

In my quest to shorten the above command (you know, save a few bytes), I found that I could "invert" the negated print command and instead use a delete as follows:

```
sed '/pattern/d;//q' file
```

which again works as expected except when `/pattern/` refers to an empty line as in `/^$/` and in that case it adds the empty line itself to the output, which is weird.

The file obviously contains an empty line in my case, which is where I want to split the content.

Any idea why this happens? Is `sed` buggy for this edge case? (the additional `//q` does quit immediately to save on processing time when using large files)

`sed --version` returns `sed (GNU sed) 4.5`

Comment: `d` starts a new cycle so I'm surprised this `q` ever works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, there is no winning solution:

```
sed '/^$/,$d' file
```

this is the best that I could find in terms of compactness, with the only drawback that it will process the whole `file`, which in some case might be undesirable (for instance, a large one)

```
sed '/^$/,$d;//q' file
```

adding the typical quit command doesn't help because the earlier range already encompasses the entire `file`

```
sed '/^$/q' file
sed '/^$/Q' file
```

these suggestions, although very compact, are not ideal (because of extra output / portability)

```
sed -n '/^$/q;p' file
```

this other suggestion is one that I had also found on my own in the meantime and it's somewhat fine given that it will quit as soon as the pattern is found, although I had hoped to get rid of the `-n` option which is where I started with all this...

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed you can run

```
sed '/pattern/Q' file
```

The `q` command prints the pattern space before quiting,
`Q` command quits silently.

<strike>I think the negated command `!p` avoids `q` to print the pattern space.</strike>

```
sed -n '/pattern/!p;//q' file
```

The `-n` option avoids `q` to print the pattern space. The other lines get printed because the address gets negated, so the `p` command is applied to all lines but those that contain `/pattern/`.
Another way to write this would be

```
sed -n '/pattern/q;p' file
```

When match `pattern`, quit (without print due to the `-n` option). All other lines, print.

In this other script, `d` command deletes all pattern space and goes directly to
the start of the `sed` script with a new line from input loaded.

```
sed '/pattern/d;//q' file
```

edit- In this case I think `//q` will never be reached when there is a match.

```
echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree\n\nfour\n\n'|sed '/^$/d;//q'
one
two
three
four
```

Maybe the line is not empty, run `cat -vet file` to see if there is something.

The new `sed` version 4.7 has a new option `--debug`, it is very useful to see how sed works.